# Pin run tool window to bottom tray

Tags: webstorm

How do I pin the run tool window to the bottom tray in Webstorm, so that it is there permanently:

[image]

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tool-windows.html#bars_and_buttons `Right click | Move To`

Comment: @LazyOne but when I shut down Webstorm the change is lost. I want it there all the time, even after I quit and restart Webstorm.

Comment: It saves it for me (PhpStorm 2022.1.3 x64 on Windows 10; no settings sync) . Maybe it's an issue with specific toolwindow? Another idea: what if you make your desired layout and save it as Default (look in the Window menu) -- will it make any difference?

Comment: No. That did not work either.

Comment: In such a cse use `Help | Contact Support...` to contact JetBrains Support Team where you can privately provide all requested information (`idea.log` file etc). Because I cannot think of any issues right now where only toolwindow layout is unable to be saved and the rest works.